# Is Activiti plugin on Eclipse unavailable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, activiti

I was trying to install the plugin for Activiti but it seems like it's no longer available as I try to add it as a new software in Eclipse Kepler SR2 with the link http://activiti.org/designer/update but it fails.
I looked on the net but didn't find a solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

The following link worked well for me on Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3):

> http://www.activiti.org/designer/archived/activiti-designer-5.18.0.zip
>
> ps: You have to download it locally first and then install it on Eclipse as an archive.

Answer (score 5):

A similar question was raised on the Alfresco Activiti forum a couple o days ago.
Alfresco changed the Activiti Community website and didnt realize the eclipse plugin was hosted there.

I opened a support request with them and reached out to the product manager.
Hopefully it will show up again soon.

If you need it urgently, it is still available (as source) on github here:

https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti-Designer

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for the response. I'm wondering if with the source here https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti-Designer  I can manage to add the plugin ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to compile the source. Need to change the github link to Graphiti though as they are referencing an old version

Comment: how do I compile the sources? I'm not able to compile the root pom with mvn install

Comment: I was able to compile the root pom. As I indicated in my earlier comment, your will need to change the location of the Graphiti library as the version used is now archived.